# Going from find('all') to paginate() breaks data in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I am trying to use afterFind to manipulate fields before displaying. It was working fine when I was using find('all') - then I switched to paginate() in order to, um, paginate. And now it's telling me the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: Event [APP/Model/Event.php, line 24]
Notice (8): Undefined index: Event [APP/Model/Event.php, line 25]
```

The afterFind script:

```
    public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
            if (isset($val['Event']['begindate'])) {
                $results[$key]['Event']['begindate'] = $this->dateFormatAfterFind(
                    $val['Event']['begindate']
                );
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

This is the controller:

```
public function index() {

    $this->Event->recursive = 2;

    $events = $this->Paginate('Event');
```

$sorted = Set::sort($events, '{n}.Event.begindate', 'asc');
        $this->set('events', $sorted);
    }

So what changed from find('all') to paginate?

Comment: I think you should use `$this->paginate('Event');`   `p` should be small.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code, may work for you

```
public function index() {
    $this->Event->recursive = 2;
    $events = $this->Paginator->paginate('Event');
    $this->set(compact('events'));
}
```